# How to print without loosing current input in linux terminal?

Tags: c, linux, terminal, ansi-escape, terminfo

So lets say we have a c program that runs in a linux terminal that continuously needs to print information. Buy also at the same time you have to be able to input text. The program has a prompt that says  `program>` so every time that the program prints something its enoguth with just add before a carriage return `\r` and then print again `program>` for avoiding the printed info to be obfuscated with the prev prompt e.g `program>Printed information 1` .

```
printed information 1
printed information 2 
program>my input
```

But if you are writing while some information is printed the current input would be covered by the printed info.

```
printed information 1
printed information 2 
printed information 3 //program>my input has been covered
program>
```

For the case I tried to make use of VT100 codes for moving the cursor like this

```
//saving cursor position and move the cursor two lines up
printf("\033[s\033[2A");
//go all the wey left and then insert a new line
printf("\r\n");

log_(logger, "some information 3");
//restore cursor position
printf("\033[u");
```

the expected behavior is this:

```
printed information 1
printed information 2
printed information 3 
program>my input
```

but the new line isn't inserted but just covers the prev printed info.

```
printed information 1
printed information 3 //printed information 2 has been covered
program>my input
```

is there any way to print information to the linux terminal without messing up the current input?

Comment: Do you actually mean a Linux console, or some other terminal emulator within an X session?  They have different capabilities!

Comment: Your code would need to take over the displaying of the input

Comment: You really need to read the characters in raw mode, then restore what was lost, and then allow editing of it (backspace, etc). It all gets very messy, which is why it generally doesn't work that way..

Answer (score 0):

The `terminfo` man page says:

> If the terminal can open a new blank line before the line where the
>   cursor is, this should be given as `il1`; this is done only from the
>   first position of a line.  The cursor must then    appear on the newly
>   blank line.  If the terminal can delete the line which the cursor is
>   on, then this should be given as `dl1`; this is done only from the first
>   position on  the  line    to be deleted.  Versions of `il1` and `dl1`
>   which take a single parameter and insert or delete that many lines can
>   be given as `il` and `dl`.

Demo:

```
echo "foo bar"; sleep .5; echo "`tput cuu1``tput il1`baz`tput ll`"; sleep 1
```